# Another form of the ratio test

Tags: sequences-and-series, absolute-convergence

Let $a_k≠0, \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$. If $$\limsup_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{k+2}}{a_k}\right|<1$$ then the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ is absolutely convergent.

I am really interested into seeing a proof of this but I cannot find one. For the original ratio test, there are many proofs but this one is different. Has anyone an idea? Thanks.

Comment: Did you see a statement of your theorem somewhere? If so please cite it or give  link.

Comment: Maybe split the series up into even and odd terms and apply the original ratio test.

Comment: the mathjax for $\limsup_{k\to\infty}$ is `\limsup_{k\to\infty}`

Answer (score 3):

To follow [leoli1's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3985547/another-form-of-the-ratio-test/3985558#comment8224224_3985547), you can do it as follows.

By the assumption and directly applying the ratio test you can show that the following two series are convergent:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_{2k}|,\quad \sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_{2k+1}|
$$

Now the partial sum of the original (absolute) series has the following estimate by the triangle inequality
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n|a_k|
\le 
\sum_{k=1\\k\textrm{ odd}}^n|a_k|
+\sum_{k=1\\k\textrm{ even}}^n|a_k|\tag{1}
$$
Taking $n\to\infty$, we are done.

---

Notes. One actually has equality in (1) and thus the triangle inequality is not needed. (Thanks to hardmath's comment below.)

Comment: @hardmath: you are absolutely right! I was only thinking of getting a bound and did not notice that. :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The condition
$$\limsup_{k\to\infty}\left\vert\frac{a_{k+2}}{a_k}\right\vert<1$$ implies that it exists $N \ge 1$ and $0 \le K \lt 1$ such that

$$\left\vert\frac{a_{k+2}}{a_k}\right\vert \le K$$ for all $k \ge N$. Therefore

$$\left\vert\frac{a_{N+2p}}{a_N}\right\vert \le K^p, \left\vert\frac{a_{N+2p+1}}{a_{N+1}}\right\vert \le K^p$$ for all $p \ge 0$ and

$$\begin{aligned}\sum_{k \ge N} \vert a_k \vert &= \sum_{k \ge N\\k\textrm{ odd}} \vert a_k \vert + \sum_{k \ge N\\k\textrm{ even}} \vert a_k \vert\\
&\le \vert a_{N+1} \vert\sum_{k \ge 0} K^{p} + \le \vert a_{N} \vert\sum_{k \ge 0} K^{p}\\
&\le \frac{2}{1-K} \max(\vert a_N \vert, \vert a_{N+1} \vert)
\end{aligned}$$

Proving that $\sum a_k$ converges absolutely.

Comment: I don't get the last inequality

Comment: I added an additional step of inequality as $\sum k^p = 1/(1-k)$.

Comment: In the penultimate line you have $+ \leq$. Maybe I was not clear earlier. Can you explain how you got 

$\le \frac{2}{1-k} \max(\vert a_N \vert, \vert a_{N+1} \vert)$ Thank you.

Comment: Did you notice how confusing (wrong) it is to overuse the letter $k$?

Comment: One last question: How can $k<1$ but $k\geq N$ and $N\geq1$. This does not make any sense to me...

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for noticing it! I changed to capital for thé bound of the ratios.